# Busy View Overlay on a form. wpf

Tags: .net, wpf

What is the best way to overlay a busy view so that User cannot interact with the form?. Tried different ways like putting a border layer on top of the form and Background to be light blur. Also Setting the cursor to Busy So that User cannot Interact. Are there any sample projects available.

But here is the problem. Setting Cursor to Busy we are not able to interact with the form that is on the back but if through tabbing (Pressing Tab ) we can go to the controls inside the form and then interact with that.?

So have anyone faced this problem before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when building [a custom Popup](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/) that contained an overlay for controls behind it. I ended up solving it by making the UserControl it's own Focus Scope, and disabling TabNavigation during a trigger

```
<local:SomeBusyView FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">
    <local:SomeBusyView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SomeBusyView}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBusy}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </local:SomeBusyView.Style>
</local:SomeBusyView>
```

Answer (score 2):

[BusyIndicator](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator&referringTitle=Home) is a purpose-built control that does all this for you.

Comment: Sorry But... this overlay is for displaying another UserControl over the form. So it cannot be used.

Comment: Don't follow. BusyIndicator is a control that does exactly what you request in your question. Its template can be customized like any other normal WPF control. Anyway, glad you found a solution.

Comment: Yes you are correct in that sense but. Rachel Solved the question as we have all custom controls.